# Cannot create Windows Store x64 packages

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-store

It seems like something is wrong in the "Select and configure packages". I can execute and build x86 and x64 packages normally, but when I go to "create package" to upload it to the windows store, x86 option appears with "mixed platform" configuration only, no x86. And in the x64 architecture the x86 configuration is selected by default,I changed it to x64 but when compiling to create the package lots of errors appears. [image]
[image]

UPDATE

I removed unnecessary build configurations, just left ARM, x64 x86.

[image]

but when building the package from the "Create package" option everything is broken again.

[image]

Comment: You've got your *solution* platform names rather messed up.  They don't mean much of anything to a .NET project, only the Project + Properties, Build configuration has an affect.  Delete bad platform names (like "Mixed Platforms") with Build + Configuration Manager, upper right combo, Edit, Remove button.  Add an "x64" platform.

Comment: I tried your solution, but as I told in the update, nothing keeps going. Although I have an x86 configuration, it does not show on the combobox when creating the package

Comment: SOLUTION: It happens that the "obj" folder was not being removed from the app package creator, just removed it and everything was working again.